# Find / Slicing Method issue

Tags: python

I was trying to use the find and string slicing method to extract the number at the end of the line. but I get this mismatch error because I came back with position 18 but from what I have read and research this position is suppose to be 18 am I missing something here?

```
str = ('X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475')
atpos = str.find(':')
print atpos

sppos = str.find(' ',atpos)
print sppos

host = float(str[atpos + 1:sppos])
print host
```

Comment: What is "this mismatch error"?

Comment: You should refrain from using `str` as an identifier as it is also the name of the type for strings. (By the way, I don't have any issue with your code.)

Comment: when I run the code I get this Please correct your code and re-run. my first line comes back as being 18 ← Mismatch I'm not sure why like I said from what I read and researched this is correct.  Again I am new to python

Comment: I'm doing an exercise in the python book section: 6.14 Exercises
Exercise 6.5 Take the following Python code that stores a string:‘
str = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475'
Use find and string slicing to extract the portion of the string after the colon
character and then use the float function to convert the extracted string into a
floating point number.

Comment: It seems like your problem is not with Python, but with some tool that's automatically grading your exercise. There's no way for us to know what the problem is from the information you've given.

Comment: Agreed, everything you showed us is correct. The problem is with whatever you're using to run the code, which you haven't showed, so we can't comment on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use the `string.split` method than looking for the specific position of the `:` delimiter,

```
_str = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475'
host = float(_str.split(':')[1])
print(host)
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that it wants me to stick to the find method.  But that string.split actually worked perfectly.

Comment: More generally, if the OP is after the *last* field of the line, and there's a possibility of more than one delimiter in the line (i.e. more than two fields), `host = float(_str.rsplit(':', 1)[-1])` might be a slightly better approach...

Answer (score 1):

str = ('X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475')
atpos = str.find(':')

sppos = str.find(' ',atpos)

host = float(str[atpos + 1:])
print (host)

Answer (score 0):

```
str = ('X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475')
atpos = str.find(':')

sppos = str.find(' ',atpos)

host = float(str[atpos + 1:])
print host
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    text = "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475";

spacePos = text.find(" ")
number = text[spacePos::1]
#not really necessary but since we are just learning and playing
strippedNumber = number.lstrip();
result = float(strippedNumber)

def reprint(printed):
    print printed  

reprint(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475 '
firstSpacePosition = str.find(' ')
num = str[firstSpacePosition+1:].rstrip()
num = float(num)
print(num)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**